# Set up constraints which depends on the frame of the superview

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to set up some width constraints, which depends on the superview width. In fact I want to use auto layout but I need to access the superviews frame to calculate the width of my subviews. All my subviews are added to a `UIView` not a view controller.

I set up the constraints in the constructor, but I want to change them in `updateConstraints`.

Constructor:

```
nfloat initialWidth = (nfloat)Math.Round((Bounds.Size.Width / 7) - (nfloat)(Math.Ceiling(Bounds.Size.Width % 7) / 2));
container0WidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create (container0, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, initialWidth);
container1WidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create (container1, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, initialWidth);

AddConstraints (new NSLayoutConstraint[] { container0WidthConstraint, container1WidthConstraint });
```

`updateConstraints`:

```
public override void UpdateConstraints ()
{
    nfloat desiredItemWidth = (nfloat)Math.Round(Bounds.Size.Width / 7);
    nfloat remainingWidth = Bounds.Size.Width - desiredItemWidth * 5;

    if (remainingWidth % 2 == 0) {
        // even
        container0WidthConstraint.Constant = remainingWidth / 2;
        container1WidthConstraint.Constant = remainingWidth / 2;
    } else {
        // odd
        container0WidthConstraint.Constant = (nfloat)Math.Floor(remainingWidth / 2);
        container1WidthConstraint.Constant = (nfloat)Math.Ceiling(remainingWidth / 2);
        }

    base.UpdateConstraints ();
}
```

The code is in C# but I added this only as additional information. Basically, I want to divide the screen in equally sized views. The only way I found which can work is through calculating as seen above.

I need the `Bounds.Size.Width` but it is always empty when I debug. How can I add constraints which depends on the frame of the superview once it is set?

**Edit:**

I think the main reason why this doesn't work for me is that this is added as subview and therefore the auto layout system has not finished yet. Where should I place `layoutIfNeeded` or should I use `layoutSubviews`? When trying the latter one I get the error "Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews". So where should I place my constraints or how should I set up my view hierarchy?

**Auto layout error:**

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11540 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7bd16b90]   (Names: '|':TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11660 H:[UIView:0x7bd16b90]-(0)-[UIView:0x7bd166a0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd114f0 H:[UIView:0x7bd166a0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7bd16a10]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd114c0 H:[UIView:0x7bd16a10]-(0)-[UIView:0x7bd163f0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11490 H:[UIView:0x7bd163f0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7bd15f90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11460 H:[UIView:0x7bd15f90]-(0)-[UIView:0x7bd15d80]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11410 H:[UIView:0x7bd15d80]-(0)-[UIView:0x7bd15ad0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd113e0 H:[UIView:0x7bd15ad0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd115c0 UIView:0x7bd16b90.width == 0.142857*TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11820 UIView:0x7bd166a0.width == 0.142857*TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11850 UIView:0x7bd16a10.width == 0.142857*TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11880 UIView:0x7bd163f0.width == 0.142857*TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd118b0 UIView:0x7bd15f90.width == 0.142857*TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11270 UIView:0x7bd15d80.width == 0.142857*TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11240 UIView:0x7bd15ad0.width == 0.142857*TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b8d6d60 H:|-(0)-[TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bc3e1e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b8ce180 H:[TestSevenEquallySpaced_SevenEquallySpacedViews:0x7bd255e0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bc3e1e0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7bd018b0 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x7bc3e1e0.height == UIWindow:0x7bc3e710.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7bd00ea0 h=--- v=--- V:[UIWindow:0x7bc3e710(1024)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bd11410 H:[UIView:0x7bd15d80]-(0)-[UIView:0x7bd15ad0]>
```

Comment: Why not use masonry? is easy to use. if you want to update the constraints just call mas_updateConstraints

Comment: Masonry seems to be another helper framework which makes setting up constraints easier. My problem seems to be the calls in the view hierarchy (see edited question).

Answer (score 0):

You should just constrain these views to your view's width rather than a constant calculated from it.

in Objective-c it would look like

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:container0
                             attribute:NSLayoutAtrributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                            multiplier:(1.0f/7.0f)
                              constant:0];
```

This would get you a view which is always 1/7 of the width of its superview.

I am guessing in C# it would be

```
NSLayoutConstraint.Create (container0, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, (1/7), 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! For my test project it does work, but I'll try it in my real project. But what is different to this constraint `H:|-0-[container1][container2(==container1)][container3(==container1)][container4(==container1)][container5(==container1)][container6(==container1)][container0(==container1)]-0-|`? The result should be the same but it isn't. I get a round issue (only in iOS 7) when doing this. Your C# try is very good! For the multiplier I had to choose `(1.0f / 7.0f)` to make it work.

Comment: Yes there is no reason you couldn't constrain them to all have the same width. What kind of rounding issue do you get? Also what constraint error?

Comment: The screen on iPad two has a width of 1024 points. You can't divide it through seven without remainder. If you do that you get some spaces between the views or near the end. So you have to use integer values to correctly size it. To make that happen some elements have to be bigger/smaller as the other one. This is what I tried but auto layout and frames doesn't work together. I've attached the auto layout error in my question. It occurs after rotation. It seems that somehow the width and height is not correctly updated.